# BUG in SQL query "select * in table" using RODBC package with ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server in R

Tags: sql, r

There seems to be a problem with ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server (Running local Ubuntu 16.04) with RODBC package (version1.3-15) in R (version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)). First of we make a query to see the size of the SQL table called **TableName**.

```
library(RODBC)
connectionString <- "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<DATABASE-URL>,<NUMBER>;Database=<DATABASE NAME>;Uid=<USER ID>;Pwd=<PASSWORD>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"

connection <- odbcDriverConnect(connectionString)
count <- sqlQuery(connection, 'select count(*) from TableName')
odbcGetErrMsg(connection)
```

Output of the above gives a count value of 200.000 (odbcGetErrMsg returns no errors), which is known to be the correct size of the SQL table called **TableName**.

*Now comes the trange part.*

```
TableName <- sqlQuery(connection, 'select * from TableName')
count = dim(TableName)[1]
odbcGetErrMsg(connection)
```

Output of the above first gives a value of 700 (odbcGetErrMsg returns no errors). But when the above code is executed again it returns another count value of 2300 i.e. it is random. When repeating above code multiple times I see the range of the count value returned is approx. between 700-8.000 (TableName has 8 columns).

None of the above outputs changes when setting ConnectionTimeout equal to either 0 or some absurd high number, respectively.

Does anybody know what is going on here? The goal is to store the full SQL table called TableName as a dataframe in R for further data processing.

Any help is much appreciated.

> Note for others with a similar problem:

I did not solve this BUG, however by shifting to Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.2 for SQL server with R package RJDBC returns the correct result. With this setup I am now able to load the full SQL table (200.000 rows and counting) into R as a dataframe for further processing.

Comment: You have me stumped +1 ... I would expect an error if something went wrong with the connection, but that apparently did not happen.

Comment: Could it be the "Connection Timeout"? Pulling the total count is a much faster process than pulling the whole table. Perhaps it is pulling as many rows as it can in 30 seconds? This would explain why you are getting a different number of rows each time.

Comment: Please show the actual output of *count* as *gives count values ranging from approx. 700-8.000* is not too clear. How can values range? Do multiple values output? Is that end number supposed to be 8,000?

Comment: Hi Parfait!
I have clarified my question. Do you have an idea what might be there going wrong here?

Comment: Is it a live system in which the data is really changing that much?

Comment: Hi xQbert,
Yes it is a dynamic SQL table, which is constantly updated (approx. one thousand new rows per day).